# Return a word with the most vowels in java

Tags: java, methods

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to return the word with the most vowels in it by taking  a list of sentences.

I know how to count the words with vowels in it and return the count. Just unable to return the word with the most vowels..

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Store the current word with the most vowels and the current vowel count in variables. When you loop through your words, if the word you're checking has more vowels then the current champ, then replace the current champ with the word and count your checking.

Comment: +1: Never expected such a variety of answers to such a simple question.

Comment: There can be more than one unique words with max number of vowels count, so remember to return Set<String>.

Answer (score 3):

```
String myString = "Java is magical";

// 1. Split your string into an array of words.
String[] words = myString.split(" ");

// 2. Initialise a max vowel count and current max count string variable
int maxVowelCount = 0;
String wordWithMostVowels = "";

// 3. Iterate over your words array.
for (String word : words) {
    // 4. Count the number of vowel in the current word
    int currentVowelCount = word.split("[aeiou]", -1).length;

    // 5. Check if it has the most vowels
    if (currentVowelCount > maxVowelCount) {

        // 6. Update your max count and current most vowel variables
        wordWithMostVowels = word;
        maxVowelCount = currentVowelCount;
    }
}

// 6. Return the word with most vowels
return wordWithMostVowels;
```

You will probably want to wrap this functionality in a method and pass your 'myString' value in to the method.

Comment: It doesn't work with repeated vowels, try it with "scenarii".

Comment: Needs a `-1` argument to split. Also doesn't handle case properly. And strictly speaking, `currentWordCount` and `maxVowelCount` aren't vowel counts, it's fine for comparison, but calling variables something they are not is pretty bad style.

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks for the quality control, that's why this is the best programming resource on the web... You may reinstate my +1 now if you like ;)

Comment: @travega: Except now you're counting consonants, and case is still a problem.

Comment: Um, now it's _more_ wrong.  If you want to use split: `word.split("[aeiou]", -1)`

Comment: Ok it has been a very long time since I've used regex (effectively!!)... It that looking more right?

Comment: Nope.  Your first one was correct, it just needed the `-1` to keep empty trailing matches, in case the word ends on a vowel (as @Jerome pointed out).

Comment: Oh that's what you meant by "needs a `-1`"... I though you were referring to the downvote you gave me. Well that was long winded but got there in the end!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I would consider simple, readable, and correct:

```
public static String findMaxVowels(Collection<String> text) {
    String best = null;
    int max = 0;
    for (String line : text) {
        // may need a better definition of "word"
        for (String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
            int count = countChars(word.toLowerCase(), "aeiou");
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                best = word;
            }
        }
    }
    return best;
}

public static int countChars(String text, String chars) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : text.toCharArray())
        if (chars.indexOf(c) >= 0)
            count += 1;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the word in a string variable and after the loop finishes return the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can split (this word is a hint) every sentence into a `List` of words and get the word with max amount of vowels. 
You'll end up with one word (the "maximum") per sentence, process this `List` of words again (you could do a neat recursive call here) and you'll obtain the word with the highest amount of vowels within your text. 
I suggest you to have a look at the static methods provided by [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection), especially:

```
public static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)
```

and eventually

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

All you have to do is implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that determines between two words which one has the highest number of vowels. It's slmost a two lines piece of code and sounds like a piece of homework.

EDIT: Finally since he got spoilers everywhere, there's that solution. With memoization there's a way to trader better performances but that's not the point I guess

```
final static Comparator <String> vowelComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public final int compare(final String word1, final String word2) {
        return vowelCount(word1) - vowelCount(word2);
    }

    private final int vowelCount(final String word) {
        int count = 0;
        for (final char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
};

public static void main(String...args) {
    //Sentences
    final List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>(3){{
        add("This is my first line");
        add("Hohoho is my second astonishing line");
        add("And finally here is my last line");
    }};

    //Store the words with highest number of vowels / sentence
    final List<String> interestingWords = new LinkedList<>();
    for (final String sentence : sentences) {
        interestingWords.add(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" ")), vowelComparator));     
    }

    System.out.println(Collections.max(interestingWords, vowelComparator));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] words = yourString.split(" ");
int max = 0;
for(String myStr: words)
    max = Math.max(max,myStr.split("[aeiou]").length);
for(String myStr: words)
    if(myStr.split("[aeiou]").length == max)
        return myStr;
```

Comment: Seems like a needlessly expensive way of counting characters... especially if you do it twice.

Comment: I guess you could keep track of which string had the max value, but it really isn't necessary, since the compiler should optimize it out anyway.

Comment: @AJMansfield Not a very constructive answer. Maybe try a less terse code example that is maybe more informative and instructive?